# Adding Jquery to root folder in my server (localhost)

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, include, root

I am learning web development and I have no idea where to place jquery.js file on my localhost server. Do I just save it as such  /var/www/jquery.js and then reference it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">?
```

Will that work or is there a particular place that is called a root folder on localhost server that I don't know about...Sorry for how dumb this sounds..

Comment: is that info enough or do you need more??

Answer (score 1):

Just put it anywhere, and include a `<script>` tag that embeds it, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/some/location/in/my/webroot/jquery.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it anywhere you want as long as the includes contains the proper path.

If you place it here:

```
/www/ajax/jquery.js
```

Your includes would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax/jquery.js"></script>
```

**BTW:** /www/ is your "web root"

---

**EDIT:**

I'd also place my JavaScript includes and scripts at the end of my body section...

[Click here to read about script location and performance.](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)

Answer (score 1):

bob,

Its always good to maintain nice heirarcy structure

do as below

Create a separate folder for js , which is javascript and place all of them there

```
root/js/jquery.js
```

and you can include

```
/js/jquery.js
```

This should be good

either you can include from google cdn also , so that you can have better performance

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
```

reference here

http://softwareas.com/google-jquery-cdn

Comment: +1 The Google reference is the way to go for speed.  http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Comment: The OP didn't ask about whether to use CDN or not.  There are pros & cons to everything, just saying.

Comment: @sparky , yep but he is very new to webdevelopment as mentioned by OP itself , its worth mentioning as it can be a huge performance tuning

Comment: I agree it's worth mentioning... I just thought I'd interject the point that there can be some disagreement about whether to use CDN or not.  Perhaps he'll investigate it further now.